# C#:Error:Object reference set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, object, reference

I am working on an accounting desktop application which gives many specific information about users.

The part that I am having trouble is here
`date = comboBoxEdit2.EditValue.ToString();` line should not be assigned as `null` as I did. But i could not find any better options and obviously, compiler gives me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`error. I'm using [devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/) and found only **.EditValue** control to check info from my database.

Thank you.

Here's my complete method,

```
public void fillCombo2()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=DLL;Database=BSSERVIS;User Id=sa;Password=1;"))
            {
                con.Open();
                string date = ("select DATE from BSSERVIS.dbo.ENUMERATION");
                date = comboBoxEdit2.EditValue.ToString();
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = null;               
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct(DATE) from BSSERVIS.dbo.ENUMERATION where WAREHOUSE_NR='" + date + "'");
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string date = dr.GetString(0);
                    comboBoxEdit2.Properties.Items.Add(date);
                }

            } 
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - reduce the problem to find the problem.  Remove the date variable and hardcode it (temporarily) - if that works then edit the question to have only the *relevant* code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to ensure that comboBoxEdit2.EditValue contains a valid date value first, perhaps (and assuming this is C#; it isn't clear from the tags you have applied) using:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(comboBoxEdit2.EditValue, out date))
{
    // Your query execution code
}
```

If it isn't a date, either don't execute the query, or set it up without the parameter.

Note also that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, if a user enters malicious data into your text box. The above is better, but you should also look at using SQL parameters to make it more secure.

DateTime.TryParse will try to parse the expression as a DateTime object, and will return true if successful and false otherwise. If successful, the out parameter date will be populated with the DateTime object.

Comment: It's a date, i'm trying to pick it up from my database. And yes it's a c# code. Sorry for bad tag choices

Comment: I mean you should check that the expression returns a date, using the code I quoted. If the user hasn't selected or entered a value, and therefore the expression is null, it won't parse as a date, and in your code you can react accordingly.

Comment: Oh, now I understood your suggestion.